# Why am I receiving segmentation fault in my insert function of a tree?

Tags: c++

The segmentation fault occurs in the insert function specifically at the `*root = x;` in the first `if` statement. The functions were already laid out and we just had to implement them so I cant add another parameter or anything. Ive been stuck on this for a while and have no idea what it could be. The root pointer was allocated memory so I really dont know what the problem is. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include "treeNode.h"
#include <iomanip>

template <class V>
class tree {
    TreeNode<V> * root;
    TreeNode<V> * cur;
    int size;

    public:
    // default constructor                                                      
    // by default, the tree is empty                                            
    tree(){
        root = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }

    // search value x in tree rooted at node t                                  
    bool treeSearch(V x, TreeNode<V>* t){
        if(t == nullptr) return false;
        if(t->getDatum() == x) return true;
        return treeSearch(x, t->getLeft()) || treeSearch(x, t->getRight());
    }

    bool treeSearch(V x){
        treeSearch(x, root);
    }


    // binary search value x in tree rooted at node t                           
    bool treeBSearch(V x, TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return false;
      if(t->getDatum() == x) return true;
      if(t->getDatum() > x)
        return treeBSearch(x, t->getLeft());
      else
        return treeBSearch(x, t->getRight());
    }

    bool treeBSearch(V x){
        return treeBSearch(x, root);
    }

    // check node t is leaf                                                     
    bool isLeaf(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t != nullptr && t->getLeft() == nullptr && t->getRight() == nullptr){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }

    // find the height of the tree rooted at node t                             
 int height(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return -1;
      if(isLeaf(t)) return 0;
      return 1 + std :: max(height(t->getLeft()), height(t->getRight()));
    }

    int height(){
        return height(root);
    }

    // find the number of nodes of tree rooted at t                             
    int nNodes(TreeNode<V>* t){
      if(t == nullptr) return 0;
      return 1 + nNodes(t->getLeft()) + nNodes(t->getRight());
    }

    int nNodes(){
        return nNodes(root);
    }


    // insert value x to the current tree object                                
    void insert(V x){
      if(root == nullptr){
        *root = x;
      }
      else{
        cur = root;
        while(cur != nullptr){
          if(cur->getDatum() < x){
            if(cur->getLeft() == nullptr){
              cur->setDatum(x);
              cur->setLeft(cur);
            }
            else{
              cur = cur->getLeft();
            }
          }
          else{
            if(cur->getRight() == nullptr){
              cur->setLeft(cur);
            }
            else{
              cur = cur->getRight();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // print out the values of tree rooted at x                                 
    // it shows the hierarchy of the tree                                       
    // it will be useful for debugging                                          
    void print(TreeNode<V> * x, int indent){
        if(x == nullptr) return;
        if (x->getRight() != nullptr) {
            print(x->getRight(), indent+4);
        }
  if (indent != 0) {
            cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
        }
        if(x->getRight() != nullptr){
            cout << " /\n" << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
        }
        cout << x->getDatum() << endl;
        if (x->getLeft() != nullptr) {
            cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ' <<" \\\n";
            print(x->getLeft(), indent+4);
        }
    }
    void print(){
        int count = 0;
        print(root, count);
    }
};
```

This is the treeNode.h file that has the constructors for each function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TreeNode{
    T datum;
    TreeNode<T>* left, * right;

    public:
    // constructor with datum value, left and right are nullptr                 
    TreeNode(T x){
        datum = x;
        left = nullptr;
        right = nullptr;
    }
    // constructor with datum value, left and right values                      
    TreeNode(T x, TreeNode<T>* lft, TreeNode<T>* rgt){
        datum = x;
        left = lft;
        right = rgt;
    }

    //destructor releases left and right nodes, if not nullptr                  
    ~TreeNode(){
        if (left) {
            delete left;
        }
        if (right) {
            delete right;
        }
    }

    // get datum value                                                          
    T getDatum(){
        return datum;
    }

    // get left pointer                                                         
    TreeNode<T>* getLeft(){
        return left;
    }

    // get right pointer                                                        
    TreeNode<T>* getRight(){
        return right;
    }
    // set the left pointer                                                     
    void setLeft(TreeNode<T>* p){
        left = p;
    }
 // set the right pointer                                                    
    void setRight(TreeNode<T>* p){
        right = p;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step in your code and find out where it breaks? I wish programming courses teachers spent an hour showing students how to use a debugger. In any case, the answer by Marcin points at one obvious issue.

Comment: `cur` should be a local variable of `insert()`, not a class member variable.

Comment: Your while loop in `insert()` never allocates any new nodes.

Answer (score 5):

This should be obvious:

```
 if(root == nullptr){
    *root = x;
    ^ ~~~~ dereferencing null pointer causes UB
  }
```

root is `nullptr`, but you dereferece it and assign - this is UB undefined behaviour, this particular one causes segment faults.

How to solve it - you should instead of dereferencing null pointer, assign value to it:

```
  if(root == nullptr){
      root = new TreeNode<V>( x );
  }
```

Comment: so how do I check if root is the first node and start the tree?

Comment: @ThomasMolloy instead of dereferencing root with *, just assign to it - see my edit.

Comment: i receive the following error when doing that: "assigning to 'TreeNode<int> *' from incompatible type
      'int' "

Comment: Your edit is wrong. `root` is a `TreeNode<V> *` so it should probably be `root = new TreeNode<V>( x );`

Comment: thats why i had to deference it

Comment: @ThomasMolloy now it should work, at least in this place.